# Stopping event propagation for select option

Tags: angularjs

I have a table.  In this I have select option placed on one of the rows.  I have on click event on row that I want to ignore.  When I select an option, it triggers the row click event which I want to prevent.  How do I prevent the click event on the row from firing when interacting with the `<select>`?

```
<table>
    <tr onclick="callme()">
        <td>
            <select ngChange="callup()">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
             </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should use ng-click and ng-change instead of onclick and ngchange

```
<table>
<tr ng-click="callme()">
  <td>
    <select ng-change="callup()">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

You can stop by adding $event to the function as follows,

```
 <table>
     <tr ng-click="callme($event)">
      <td>
         <select ng-change="callup()">
           <option>1</option>
           <option>2</option>
        </select>
       </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
```

and in controller,

```
    $scope.callMe= function($event) {
       $event.stopPropagation();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass event in callme() function -

```
  <table>
     <tr onclick="callme($event)">
      <td>
         <select ngChange="callup()">
           <option>1</option>
           <option>2</option>
        </select>
       </td>
     </tr>
   </table>

    $scope.callMe= function($event) {
       $event.stopPropagation();
    }
```